# httpinvoke and pouchdb promise stalling

Tags: couchdb, promise

after making an httpinvoke call, I need to load couchDB but the promise is not passing on.

```
createDB: function() {
    var db = new PouchDB('options');
    db.info().then(function (info){
        if(info.doc_count <= 10000) {
            var db = new PouchDB('options');
            db.destroy().then(function(info){
                httpinvoke('http://localhost:9080/secure/sync.form','GET');
            }).then(function (res){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); //This never gets called but if I move this then() block to httpinvoke(xxx).then()  it does get called
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises chain by *return* values. If you want to make anything meaningful with a promise you have to *return* it. A promise represents a value + time, your `httpinvoke` call doesn't return is similar to a synchronus function not returning.

```
createDB: function() {
    var db = new PouchDB('options');
    db.info().then(function (info){
        if(info.doc_count <= 10000) {
            var db = new PouchDB('options');
            db.destroy().then(function(info){
                return httpinvoke('...','GET'); // NOTE THE RETURN
            }).then(function (res){
                console.log(res); // console already shows JSON 
            }); // no need to `catch anyway`, errors are errors let's not suppress. 
        }
    });
}
```

Also note that promise

Comment: That is what I thought before. And I tried returning the httpinvoke() call. But it returns a function function () {
            /* jshint expr:true */
            cb && cb(new Error('abort'));
            /* jshint expr:false */
            try {
                xhr.abort();
            } catch(err){
            }
        }          . Instead of that, if I change it and make it httpinvoke('...','GET').then(function(res) {console.log(res)});      That works fine. It is just when I try to chain the promise it is not going through ... ?

Comment: That's pretty impossible. Is it possible that it just resolves with a function? What happens if you `return httpinvoke(...).then(function(r){ return r; })` and chain to that?

Comment: I think that will work since we are explicitly returning the ajax response. I just changed the httpinvoke library to reqwest library, and the code worked. So there might be some bug with httpinvoke library. Will probably report it a bit later. Ofcourse I had to return the call, but it worked with request. Thanks for your response.